# Difference between AFJSONRequestSerializer and AFHTTPRequestSerializer

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

What actually is the reason that my request works for `AFJSONRequestSerializer` and doesnt for `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`?

I have set

```
responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes?.insert("application/json")
```

for `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` and it doesn't work, but should.

I just send simple dictionary:

```
{
    "approval_required" = 1;
    birthdate = "2016-03-11";
    gender = male;
    name = Bartolo;
    password = password1234;
    username = "super user";
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385353/afnetworking-2-0-cannot-post-with-json-from-ios) is similar question, but there is no explanation **WHY** it is like that.

**Can anyone explain?**

Comment: Look at the method `-requestBySerializingRequest:withParameters:error:`. It serialize differently the parameters: set `setHTTPBody:` at the end, and the headers too. And you set the "response", if not set, in you case, it should return `NSData` (to transform into JSON) instead of NSDictionary/NSArray at top level representing JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `acceptableContentTypes` has little to do with the format of a request, ie whether it is HTTP request or JSON request. A request serializer's fundamental responsibility is to create a request in the specified format. Thus, the choice of `requestSerializer` dictates whether you are creating a HTTP request (e.g. a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) or JSON request (e.g. a `Content-Type` of `application/json`). The `acceptableContentTypes` merely allows the request to specify in what format(s) your app will accept responses. (And, frankly, you shouldn't specify `acceptableContentTypes`, but rather just use the correct `responseSerializer`.) But the request format and the accepted response format are two completely different things. In fact, it's not uncommon to have a web service that only accepts HTTP requests, and only provides JSON responses.

In your case, it sounds like you have a web service that is expecting a JSON request. When you specify `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, the request will not be in JSON format and will likely not be understood. And specifying `acceptableContentTypes` does not alter the fact that the request, itself, isn't JSON.

---

By the way, tools like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) are very useful for debugging network code, and would be illuminating in diagnosing the difference in these two types of requests. If you use one of these tools to watch the raw requests/responses, the difference will jump out at you.

Comment: Let me understand it well;) `requestSerializer` defines format for server (depending on what it is prepared for) and `acceptableContentTypes` is for app (depending on what my app is prepared for) right?

Comment: The `requestSerializer` defines the format of the request that the app will create and send to the server. And web services are generally designed to accept requests of only a particular type. The nature of the format of the response that the web service will generate and/or that the app will accept is a different question.

Comment: Thank you;) that is what I needed to know